# TypeError: element.type.toLowerCase is not a function

Tags: react-router, react-redux, react-dom, react-dom-server, react-ssr

I am facing an issue while setting up SSR for a react app.The Server side code for the render is as below:

```
    app.use((req, res) => {
    const context = {}

    const body = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
        React.createElement(
            Provider, { store },
            React.createElement(
                StaticRouter, { location: req.url, context: context },
                React.createElement(Layout, null, React.createElement(Routes))
            )
        )
    )
    if (context.url) {
        res.redirect(context.url)
    } else {
        res.status(200).send(template({ body }))
    }
})
```

The route config is as below:
Routes.js

```
const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
      <Route path="*" component={NotFound}/>
    </Switch>
  )
}

    export default Routes
```

App.js

```
const App = () => {  
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
        <Layout>
              {router}
        </Layout>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
    );
}

export default App
```

It throwing the below error:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
TypeError: element.type.toLowerCase is not a function
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.renderDOM (../node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:2304:28)
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.render (../node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:2298:21)
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (../node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:2234:19)
    at Object.renderToString (../node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:2501:25)
    at app.use (../server.js:59:33)
```

When i tried printing   `console.log(React.createElement(Routes));`  it shows as below:

```
{ '$$typeof': Symbol(react.element),
  type: [Function: Routes],
  key: null,
  ref: null,
  props: {},
  _owner: null,
  _store: {} }
```

I have created the CompiledRoutes file from the Routes file using babel and I am importing it into server.js as below:

```
const Routes = require('./client/CRoutes').default
```

Can someone pls guide me  what could be the issue here?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing

```
React.createElement(Layout, null, React.createElement(Routes))
```

to

```
React.createElement(Layout, null, React.createElement(Routes.default))
```

You might be using `require` on the server-side, instead of `import`, which results in some discrepancies.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.I tried using as you suggested but it didn't help.I am not sure what going wrong.

Comment: Can you share how you are importing/requiring the `Routes` component?

Also, I am confused by the two exports in your second snippet. Are they two different files?

Comment: Thanks .I have updated the question.Yes they are different files.

Comment: I was able to resolve this by adding default after Layout.